# Docker can't find dependencies in go.mod file

Tags: docker, go, makefile

I'm working in a project with **GoLang** and **Docker** and using go.mod to maintain the dependencies.
The project works fine when i build without docker, but when i try to build the docker image, this error appears:

```
internal/server/server.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/gorilla/mux" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux (from $GOPATH)
cmd/root.go:7:2: cannot find package "github.com/spf13/cobra" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/spf13/cobra (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/github.com/spf13/cobra (from $GOPATH)
make: *** [Makefile:30: build] Error 1
```

Dockerfile

```
# Build Stage
FROM lacion/alpine-golang-buildimage:1.9.7 AS build-stage

LABEL app="build-status-hub"
LABEL REPO="https://github.com/MSLacerda/status-hub"

ENV PROJPATH=/go/src/github.com/MSLacerda/status-hub

# Because of https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14914
ENV PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin

ADD . /go/src/github.com/MSLacerda/status-hub
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/MSLacerda/status-hub

RUN make build
```

> The Dockerfile actually has more instructions, but i placed here just only  the part when the console shows the error.

The Makefile

```
build:
    @echo "building ${BIN_NAME} ${VERSION}"
    @echo "GOPATH=${GOPATH}"
    go build -ldflags "-X github.com/MSLacerda/status-hub/version.GitCommit=${GIT_COMMIT}${GIT_DIRTY} -X github.com/MSLacerda/status-hub/version.BuildDate=${BUILD_DATE}" -o bin/${BIN_NAME}
```

go.mod

```
module github.com/MSLacerda/status-hub

require (
    github.com/Sirupsen/logrus v1.0.6
    github.com/gorilla/mux v1.7.0
    github.com/spf13/cobra v0.0.3
    github.com/spf13/viper v1.2.0
    golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20190219172222-a4c6cb3142f2 // indirect
)
```

Comment: You can't use modules in GOPATH without setting `GO111MODULE=on`, and you're using go1.9.7 which came out long before go modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What is happing?**

When you are trying to build the app the required deps are not installed in the docker image

**Why it occurs in the docker image and not in my local dev env?**

In your local dev env you install/get the required deps running commands like the following example.

```
$ go get -u github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/cmd/swagger
```

But each container/image will be an empty/clean env. You need to tell for the docker container that is required to first install the deps.

**Solution**

- Use Makefiles to create task/commands for your project. See more over it [here](https://sohlich.github.io/post/go_makefile/)
- Create a make file command to install the deps and build the project

Makefile Example

```
.PHONY: setup
setup: @echo Installing dependencies:
    go get -u github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/cmd/swagger

.PHONY: build
build: setup
    go build -o $(BINARY) $(APP_FILE)
```

- Then the command `make build` need be called to create your image instead of the go build used currently.
- Instead of using the `go get` commands for each dependency use the go dep manager to do it. Following the example.

Makefile

```
.PHONY: setup
setup: @echo Installing dependencies:
    dep ensure
```

See more about it [here](https://golang.github.io/dep/docs/daily-dep.html)

Comment: Thank you, i forgot to put the `RUN make get-deps` in my Dockerfile and your answer remember me to do this... And i created a setup command too.